# Why the popup is not showing second time in leaflet marker

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I am drawing a **marker** in my [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map and on clicking the marker I am showing a popup message.

If I click the marker **first time** I see the popup message. But if I close the popup message and then **again click** the marker I don't see the popup message though the code enters inside the on click event code block as the console message is printed.

Here is my code of click event

```
circle.on("click",function(ev){
    var velocity=this.options.speed;
    console.log(velocity.toFixed(2));
    var layer=ev.target;
    layer.bindPopup('Speed: '+velocity.toFixed(2));
    console.log("Where is pop");
    layer.openPopup();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're creating Popup each time when user click the marker. Probably, this is creating problem.

You need to use the `bindPopup()` function only once i.e when you create the **marker**. And only use `openPopup()` inside `click` function. Try this

```
//Place below two lines where you create the marker
var velocity=this.options.speed; //you might need to change this line to get the speed value
circle.bindPopup('Speed: '+velocity.toFixed(2));

//open the popup when user click the marker
circle.on("click",function(ev){
    layer.openPopup();
});
```